# Can you help me with my number guessing game

Tags: batch-file

Here is my code

```
    @echo off
    echo Welcome to the number game!
    echo Pick a number through 1 and 10
    set /a bottomlimit = 1
    set /a upperlimit = 10
    set /a result= %bottomlimit% + %RANDOM% %% (%upperlimit% - %bottomlimit%  + 1)
    echo %result%
    set v1=1
    set v2=2
    set v3=3
    set v4=4
    set v5=5
    set v6=6
    set v7=7
    set v8=8
    set v9=9
    set v10=10
    set /p you= 
    pause 
    if "%you%==%result%" goto end
    break
    if not "%you%==%result%" goto lose
    :end
    echo Congrats!!!! You Won!!
    pause
    :lose
    echo You Lose!!
    pause
```

My goal is to make a game that will match your number with a randomly generated number from 1 to 10. So can you help me with it and find anything wrong with it.
So far what I found was that the lose works, but when you win it says that you won then you lose. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: After the pause (in :end) execution is going to continue unless you stop it. After the pause comes the `echo You Lose!!!` which is what you are seeing.

Comment: Before :lose add the following code: `GOTO :EOF` on its own line.

Comment: @Tridge323 Please use the edit link below tag __batch-file__ below text of your question and edit the title of your question. The question as is can be answered with "Yes, I can" or "No, I can't". So the question is definitely not good, isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

You have not told :end to stop before going to :lose.

To do this,either type `exit` after the pause. That will Close the window.

You could also put these two lines after `@echo off`:

```
goto session
:session
```

after those lines would be the game.

Then, after the pause in :end, you would add

```
goto session
```

To prevent it from Going to :lose .

Comment: You'd want to say `exit /b` otherwise the command prompt would completely close after the game ended.